# C# Convert Date To Double

Tags: c#, vba, datetime, type-conversion

I have written a function in VBA which creates a code from the properties of a file.
I need a developer to do the same in C# on their end.

The developer says it is not possible to do the same in c#.

So in VBA, part of my process is to convert a date to a double. The way VBA does this is to basically count the number of days between the given date and 1 Jan 1900. So 19 Mar 2014 would be a double value of 41,717.

How would I say write a function in C# (not a language I am familiar with) that would convert a date data type to the number of days that have passed since 1 January 1900?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using VBA, you might actually be looking for the DateTime.ToOADate function, documented here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/x2k67kb6(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: @Mark `ToOADate` is close, but _slightly_ different (2 days to be exact) than the number of days since 1/1/1900.

Comment: @DStanley The reason I think he is looking for OADate and not the function that he is describing, is because is example input/output that he gives fits for OADate, but not for his description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtracting two `DateTime`s gives you a `TimeSpan`. You can just use `TimeSpan.TotalDays` to get the number of days between two dates:

```
double days = (DateTime.Today - new DateTime(1900,1,1)).TotalDays;
```

If the `DateTime` has a time component it will be represented as fractions of a day, so for example:

```
 // current date and time (16:24:15)
 (new DateTime(2014, 3, 18, 16, 24, 15) - new DateTime(1900,1,1)).TotalDays
```

would give you 41714.6835069444

Note that the result is 2 days different that using `CDbl()` in VBA since a date in VBA is represented by the number of days since 12/30/1899 rather than 1/1/1900.

Comment: I'd agree with D Stanley. `The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899.`

Answer (score 1):

Use .net DateTime method ToOADate() wich returns a [double representing the OLE Automation date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
VBA uses this [same format to representa a date as a double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/gg278460%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly 3 days difference.  Which might be because I'm in NZ at GMT + 12.
Or it might be because I was multiplying a double by "TicksPerDay" and .Net doesn't allow for some strange numbers.

DateTime.FromOADate(vbaTime) was the perfect solution for me moving dates between MS Access and C#.

Incidentally, I suspect that this is a result of the "date calculation issue" that Joel Spolsky refered to:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

when discussing Lotus notes compatibility in Excel as the program manager at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, without using OLE Automation:

```
'get time elapsed since some earlier point in time, such as midnight today
Dim tim As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(Today)

'calc the time elapsed in fractional seconds
'note that tim.Seconds only provides whole seconds, so add tim.Milliseconds
Dim tsec As Double = tim.Hours * 3600 + tim.Minutes * 60 + tim.Seconds + tim.Milliseconds / 1000
```